# How to configure Jetty 9 to listen to multiple ports using Gretty

Tags: java, configuration, webserver, jetty, gretty

How do I configure Jetty 9 to listen to multiple ports using Gretty. 
I just want to configure Jetty to listen to more than one port. I don't want multiple instances nor multiple webapps, just one Jetty, one webapp, but listening to 2 or more ports.

I have tried adding `serverConfigFile = file("src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jetty-webserver.xml")` in the Gretty configuration but then I get the error below.

jetty-webserver.xml

```
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
    <Call name="addConnector">
      <Arg>
          <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
            <Set name="host"><Property name="jetty.host" /></Set>
            <Set name="port"><Property name="jetty.port" default="8080"/></Set>
            <Set name="maxIdleTime">300000</Set>
            <Set name="Acceptors">2</Set>
            <Set name="statsOn">false</Set>
            <Set name="confidentialPort">8443</Set>
        <Set name="lowResourcesConnections">20000</Set>
        <Set name="lowResourcesMaxIdleTime">5000</Set>
          </New>
      </Arg>
    </Call>

    <Call name="addConnector">
      <Arg>
          <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
            <Set name="host"><Property name="jetty.host" /></Set>
            <Set name="port"><Property name="jetty.port" default="8081"/></Set>
            <Set name="maxIdleTime">300000</Set>
            <Set name="Acceptors">2</Set>
            <Set name="statsOn">false</Set>
        <Set name="lowResourcesConnections">20000</Set>
        <Set name="lowResourcesMaxIdleTime">5000</Set>
          </New>
      </Arg>
    </Call>
</Configure>
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:86)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.nodeClass(XmlConfiguration.java:364)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.newObj(XmlConfiguration.java:754)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.itemValue(XmlConfiguration.java:1125)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.value(XmlConfiguration.java:1030)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.call(XmlConfiguration.java:721)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:417)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:298)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:248)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$configure.call(Unknown Source)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:128)
>           at org.akhikhl.gretty.JettyConfigurerImpl.applyJettyXml(JettyConfigurerImpl.groovy:63)
>           at org.akhikhl.gretty.JettyConfigurer$applyJettyXml$0.call(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:136)
>           at org.akhikhl.gretty.JettyServerConfigurer.createAndConfigureServer(JettyServerConfigurer.groovy:65)
>           at org.akhikhl.gretty.JettyServerConfigurer.createAndConfigureServer(JettyServerConfigurer.groovy)
>           at org.akhikhl.gretty.JettyServerConfigurer$createAndConfigureServer.call(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
>           at org.akhikhl.gretty.JettyServerManager.startServer(JettyServerManager.groovy:44)
>           at org.akhikhl.gretty.ServerManager$startServer$0.call(Unknown Source)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:128)
>           at org.akhikhl.gretty.Runner.run(Runner.groovy:121)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:71)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
>           at org.akhikhl.gretty.Runner.main(Runner.groovy:48) Exception in thread "Thread-29" org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException:
>   Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin\java.exe''
>   finished with non-zero exit value 1
>           at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:396)
>           at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultJavaExecAction.execute(DefaultJavaExecAction.java:38)
>           at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecActionFactory.javaexec(DefaultExecActionFactory.java:129)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.javaexec(DefaultProject.java:1103)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.javaexec(DefaultProject.java:1098)
>           at org.gradle.api.Project$javaexec$6.call(Unknown Source)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:127)
>           at org.akhikhl.gretty.DefaultLauncher.javaExec(DefaultLauncher.groovy:93)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:104)
>           at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:326)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:352)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:68)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:156)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:168)
>           at org.akhikhl.gretty.LauncherBase$_launchThread_closure4.doCall(LauncherBase.groovy:259)
>           at org.akhikhl.gretty.LauncherBase$_launchThread_closure4.doCall(LauncherBase.groovy)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:104)
>           at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:326)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:264)
>           at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)
>           at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
>           at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:405)
>           at groovy.lang.Closure.run(Closure.java:492)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

I have looked at this post and looking for the solution with Gretty.
[how to configure jetty to listen to multiple ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905098/how-to-configure-jetty-to-listen-to-multiple-ports)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your Gretty configuration is fine. Your problem is with your new jetty-webserver.xml configuration.
Take a look to Jetty 9.x documentation:[jetty connector docs](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/configuring-connectors.html)
(look at chapter "HTTP Configuration")

Jetty provides a set of sample configuration files, e.g. [jetty-http.xml](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.x/jetty-server/src/main/config/etc/jetty-http.xml)

Take jetty-http.xml content and modify to add a new http connector like this (v9.4.x):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_3.dtd">
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">

  <!-- =========================================================== -->
  <!-- Add a HTTP Connector.                                       -->
  <!-- Configure an o.e.j.server.ServerConnector with a single     -->
  <!-- HttpConnectionFactory instance using the common httpConfig  -->
  <!-- instance defined in jetty.xml                               -->
  <!--                                                             -->
  <!-- Consult the javadoc of o.e.j.server.ServerConnector and     -->
  <!-- o.e.j.server.HttpConnectionFactory for all configuration    -->
  <!-- that may be set here.                                       -->
  <!-- =========================================================== -->
  <Call name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
      <New id="httpConnector" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
        <Arg name="server"><Ref refid="Server" /></Arg>
        <Arg name="acceptors" type="int"><Property name="jetty.http.acceptors" deprecated="http.acceptors" default="-1"/></Arg>
        <Arg name="selectors" type="int"><Property name="jetty.http.selectors" deprecated="http.selectors" default="-1"/></Arg>
        <Arg name="factories">
          <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ConnectionFactory">
            <Item>
              <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnectionFactory">
                <Arg name="config"><Ref refid="httpConfig" /></Arg>
                <Arg name="compliance"><Call class="org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpCompliance" name="valueOf"><Arg><Property name="jetty.http.compliance" default="RFC7230_LEGACY"/></Arg></Call></Arg>
              </New>
            </Item>
          </Array>
        </Arg>
        <Set name="host"><Property name="jetty.http.host" deprecated="jetty.host" /></Set>
        <Set name="port"><Property name="jetty.http.port" deprecated="jetty.port" default="8080" /></Set>
        <Set name="idleTimeout"><Property name="jetty.http.idleTimeout" deprecated="http.timeout" default="30000"/></Set>
        <Set name="acceptorPriorityDelta"><Property name="jetty.http.acceptorPriorityDelta" deprecated="http.acceptorPriorityDelta" default="0"/></Set>
        <Set name="acceptQueueSize"><Property name="jetty.http.acceptQueueSize" deprecated="http.acceptQueueSize" default="0"/></Set>
        <Get name="SelectorManager">
          <Set name="connectTimeout"><Property name="jetty.http.connectTimeout" default="15000"/></Set>
        </Get>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </Call>
<Call name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
      <New id="httpConnector2" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
        <Arg name="server"><Ref refid="Server" /></Arg>
        <Arg name="acceptors" type="int"><Property name="jetty.http.acceptors" deprecated="http.acceptors" default="-1"/></Arg>
        <Arg name="selectors" type="int"><Property name="jetty.http.selectors" deprecated="http.selectors" default="-1"/></Arg>
        <Arg name="factories">
          <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ConnectionFactory">
            <Item>
              <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnectionFactory">
                <Arg name="config"><Ref refid="httpConfig" /></Arg>
                <Arg name="compliance"><Call class="org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpCompliance" name="valueOf"><Arg><Property name="jetty.http.compliance" default="RFC7230_LEGACY"/></Arg></Call></Arg>
              </New>
            </Item>
          </Array>
        </Arg>
        <Set name="host"><Property name="jetty.http.host" deprecated="jetty.host" /></Set>
        <Set name="port"><Property name="jetty.http.port" deprecated="jetty.port" default="8081" /></Set>
        <Set name="idleTimeout"><Property name="jetty.http.idleTimeout" deprecated="http.timeout" default="30000"/></Set>
        <Set name="acceptorPriorityDelta"><Property name="jetty.http.acceptorPriorityDelta" deprecated="http.acceptorPriorityDelta" default="0"/></Set>
        <Set name="acceptQueueSize"><Property name="jetty.http.acceptQueueSize" deprecated="http.acceptQueueSize" default="0"/></Set>
        <Get name="SelectorManager">
          <Set name="connectTimeout"><Property name="jetty.http.connectTimeout" default="15000"/></Set>
        </Get>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </Call>
</Configure>
```

*Replace 8081 port for your new port number in httpConnector2.

EDITED: Added XML SCHEMA headers.

EDITED 2: Sample configuration for Jetty v9.2.x:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_3.dtd">


<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">

  <!-- =========================================================== -->
  <!-- Add a HTTP Connector.                                       -->
  <!-- Configure an o.e.j.server.ServerConnector with a single     -->
  <!-- HttpConnectionFactory instance using the common httpConfig  -->
  <!-- instance defined in jetty.xml                               -->
  <!--                                                             -->
  <!-- Consult the javadoc of o.e.j.server.ServerConnector and     -->
  <!-- o.e.j.server.HttpConnectionFactory for all configuration    -->
  <!-- that may be set here.                                       -->
  <!-- =========================================================== -->
  <Call name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
        <Arg name="server"><Ref refid="Server" /></Arg>
        <Arg name="acceptors" type="int"><Property name="http.acceptors" default="-1"/></Arg>
        <Arg name="selectors" type="int"><Property name="http.selectors" default="-1"/></Arg>
        <Arg name="factories">
          <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ConnectionFactory">
            <Item>
              <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnectionFactory">
                <Arg name="config"><Ref refid="httpConfig" /></Arg>
              </New>
            </Item>
          </Array>
        </Arg>
        <Set name="host"><Property name="jetty.host" /></Set>
        <Set name="port">8080</Set>
        <Set name="idleTimeout"><Property name="http.timeout" default="30000"/></Set>
        <Set name="soLingerTime"><Property name="http.soLingerTime" default="-1"/></Set>
        <Set name="acceptorPriorityDelta"><Property name="http.acceptorPriorityDelta" default="0"/></Set>
        <Set name="selectorPriorityDelta"><Property name="http.selectorPriorityDelta" default="0"/></Set>
        <Set name="acceptQueueSize"><Property name="http.acceptQueueSize" default="0"/></Set>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </Call>
<Call name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
        <Arg name="server"><Ref refid="Server" /></Arg>
        <Arg name="acceptors" type="int"><Property name="http.acceptors" default="-1"/></Arg>
        <Arg name="selectors" type="int"><Property name="http.selectors" default="-1"/></Arg>
        <Arg name="factories">
          <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ConnectionFactory">
            <Item>
              <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnectionFactory">
                <Arg name="config"><Ref refid="httpConfig" /></Arg>
              </New>
            </Item>
          </Array>
        </Arg>
        <Set name="host"><Property name="jetty.host" /></Set>
        <Set name="port">8081</Set>
        <Set name="idleTimeout"><Property name="http.timeout" default="30000"/></Set>
        <Set name="soLingerTime"><Property name="http.soLingerTime" default="-1"/></Set>
        <Set name="acceptorPriorityDelta"><Property name="http.acceptorPriorityDelta" default="0"/></Set>
        <Set name="selectorPriorityDelta"><Property name="http.selectorPriorityDelta" default="0"/></Set>
        <Set name="acceptQueueSize"><Property name="http.acceptQueueSize" default="0"/></Set>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </Call>
</Configure>
```

Comment: If I use the file you provided I get the following error: "WARN  Config error at <Call name="addConnector"><Arg><New id="httpConnector"...". The first Call-tag is printed, the one with id httpConnector. And then I get a callstack the ends in: "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlParser$Node at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.newArray(XmlConfiguration.java:872)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.itemValue(XmlConfiguration.java:1129)".

Comment: hi @user1766169 what is your Jetty 9 version? I can try it.

Comment: I'm using "servletContainer = 'jetty9'" in the Gretty configuration which corresponds to Jetty 9.2.22.v20170606 according to this site: http://akhikhl.github.io/gretty-doc/Switching-between-servlet-containers.html

Comment: I tried with last version 9.4.18 and it works.
If you have docker you can do this simple test:
(1) - copy my custom jetty-http.xml file in your local drive.
(2) - run jetty image: docker run -it -v /YOUR_LOCAL_PATH/jetty-http.xml:/usr/local/jetty/etc/jetty-http.xml jetty
(3) - check in logs that both ports are opened:
2019-08-19 05:55:27.101:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@6a2bcfcb{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2019-08-19 05:55:27.102:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@4de8b406{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8081}

Comment: I tried with version 9.2.22 using "run jetty image: docker run -it -v /YOUR_LOCAL_PATH/jetty-http.xml:/usr/local/jetty/etc/jetty-http.xml jetty:9.2.22", and I got your error message. If you can, try with last Jetty version or adapt my xml to v9.2.22.

Comment: You can try with Gretty "servletContainer='jetty94'" to test my configuration with Jetty 9.4

Comment: Added sample configuration for Jetty v9.2.x.

Comment: The server starts with the Jetty-file for 9.2.X and prints the log Jetty 9.2.X... started and listening on ports 8080, 8081 but when I go to http://localhost:8080 I get ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED.

Comment: Check your server binding is 0.0.0.0 for public access or 127.0.0.1 for localhost access.
ERR_SCOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED is usually a problem with DNS or bonded interfaces.
If you are testing with docker containers, remember to add your port mappings (e.g. "-p 8080:8080 -p 8081:8081") to expose your ports in the command line. If you open 127.0.0.1:8080 or 127.0.0.1:8081 you should get an EMPTY response instead of one "not connected". In any case, the logs can indicate that both ports have been opened correctly.